# Displaying a mat-select scroll bar at all times (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am creating an app that has a lot of mat-select items within it, the problem being that when there is more content than the select can show, it is not obvious that you need to scroll to view the rest (this is based on a lot of user feedback). So, I am trying to have the scrollbar displaying at all times. I have tried this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
  width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #d9d9d8;
  width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: $baseBlue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

but it still does not display! (I am using Chrome btw).

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Did you find some css to do the trick?